# ASP.Net How can I respond to a request sent to my generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets assume I have told a 3rd party to send a request to my generic handler based at {http://myIp/Myhandler.ashx}. How can I respond to the request that they send? I have the function process request which gives me access to the context object but how can this be used to ensure my response goes back to the same place that the request originated from and thus acting as a reply to their request. I tried constructing an HTTPResponse object and sending it to their server but this did not work. I am trying to reply to them with an OK message and give them a web address to redirect the user to.

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            string status = context.Request.Params["Status"];
            string statusDetail = context.Request.Params["StatusDetail"];

            switch (status.ToUpper())
            {
                case "OK":
                    {
                        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

                        content.Append("Status=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("OK"));
                        content.Append("&RedirectURL=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://http://myip:myport/Error.aspx?Error=SUCCESS"));
                        content.Append("&StatusDetail=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("OK"));


                        HttpWebResponse response = SendPOSTRequest("http://theirip.page", content.ToString(), "", "", true);
}
}
```

Comment: I should add that I do not intend to redirect to a page for errors. This is only a test page.

Comment: Love it when people downvote without an explanation. Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `context` parameter to setup the response to be sent.  Since your response is a string, you can just use `Write`:

```
context.Response.Write(content.ToString());
```

You'll also want to set some of the response headers:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
```

Comment: `HttpContext` doesn't have a `Write` method; you need to `Write` to the `Response` object.

Comment: You have a typo in there. It should be context.Response.Write(content.ToString()). I will try that now.

Answer (score 6):

You use `context.Response` to write to the response stream.  (You can use use `Write` as you go rather than putting everything in a string builder and writing that; it will automatically buffer it appropriately.) ASP, IIS, and HTTP will ensure that writing to the response stream goes towards whatever actually sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpWebResponse response = Context.Response
```

or simple write straight to it

```
Context.Response = SendPOSTRequest ....
```